Azure AI search handling special characters
I have created the following index in Azure AI search,
{
    "name": "classic-index",
    "defaultScoringProfile": "",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "Id",
            "type": "Edm.String",
            "searchable": false,
            "filterable": true,
            "retrievable": true,
            "sortable": true,
            "facetable": true,
            "key": true,
            "synonymMaps": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Text",
            "type": "Edm.String",
            "searchable": true,
            "filterable": true,
            "retrievable": true,
            "sortable": true,
            "facetable": true,
            "key": false,
            "analyzer": "specialcharanalyzer",
            "synonymMaps": []
        }
    ],
    "scoringProfiles": [],
    "corsOptions": null,
    "suggesters": [],
    "analyzers": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
            "name": "specialcharanalyzer",
            "tokenizer": "classic",
            "tokenFilters": [
                "lowercase",
                "custom_ngram_filter"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "normalizers": [],
    "tokenFilters": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.NGramTokenFilterV2",
            "name": "custom_ngram_filter",
            "minGram": 2,
            "maxGram": 20
        }
    ],
    "charFilters": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.MappingCharFilter",
            "name": "char_mapping",
            "mappings": [
                "-=>",
                ".=>",
                "/=>",
                "\\u0020=>"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "encryptionKey": null,
    "semantic": null,
    "vectorSearch": null
}

The tokens it generates is mostly fine apart from the following two scenarios,
First scenario:
{
    "text": "c->a",
    "analyzer": "specialcharanalyzer"
}

Second scenario:
{
    "text": "c/a",
    "analyzer": "specialcharanalyzer"
}

The above two scenarios does not generate any tokens. What is the best way to handle unsafe and reserved characters when indexing the documents?

The defined a character filter to remove special characters like -, (), +, ., and spaces. Example: a Text  like +1 (425) 703-6214 (tokenized as "1", "425", "703", "6214") won't show up in a "3-62" query because that content doesn't actually exist in the index.

According to this MSDOC:

A partial term search might include a combination of fragments, often with special characters such as hyphens, dashes, or slashes that are part of the query string. Common use cases include parts of a phone number, URL, codes, or hyphenated compound words.
The filter above removes -, (, ), +, ., and spaces from the [input], as described in this MSDOC.


To work with the above, the analyzer should be standard.lucene.
Update the Custom Analyzer index configuration as follows:
{
    "name": "classic-index",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name":  "Iddetails",
            "type": "Edm.String",
            "searchable": false,
            "filterable": true,
            "retrievable": true,
            "sortable": true,
            "facetable": true,
            "key": true
        },
        {
            "name": "TextName",
            "type": "Edm.String",
            "searchable": true,
            "filterable": true,
            "retrievable": true,
            "sortable": true,
            "facetable": true,
            "analyzer": "standard.lucene"
        }
    ],
    "analyzers": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
            "name": "specialcharanalyzer",
            "tokenizer": "standard_v2",
            "charFilters": [
                "char_mapping",
                "pattern_replace_filter"
            ],
            "tokenFilters": [
                "lowercase",
                "custom_ngram_filter"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "charFilters": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.MappingCharFilter",
            "name": "char_mapping",
            "mappings": [
                "->=>",
                "/=>"
            ]
        },
        {
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.PatternReplaceCharFilter",
            "name": "pattern_replace_filter",
            "pattern": "([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[\\-\\/]+([a-zA-Z0-9]+)",
            "replacement": "$1 $2"
        }
    ],
    "tokenFilters": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.NGramTokenFilterV2",
            "name": "custom_ngram_filter",
            "minGram": 2,
            "maxGram": 20
        }
    ]
}

For adding character filters in Azure AI Search, refer to this MSDOC.
I have added sample data below into the index using -> and /:
{ "@search.action": "upload", "id": "9", "phone_number": "321->0199" },

{ "@search.action": "upload", "id": "10", "phone_number": "321/0199" }

Output with  ->:
POST https://AzureSearchServiceName.search.windows.net/indexes/IndexName/analyze?api-version=2024-07-01  HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
api-key: {{apiKey}}

{
    "text": "425/555",
    "analyzer": "standard.lucene"
}


Output with  /:


I will try this. Just wandering what happens if the user searches for "c->a"? @Sampath

Will display sample results as above.
